# Updating an OpenCV tracker with a bounding box in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am using an OpenCV tracker to perform face tracking in videos, together with a face detector every few frames. If a face is detected by the face detector, I would like to update the tracker with the "detected" bounding box. I see that there is an option to enter a Rect in the C++ implementation but for some reason not in the python implementation [as written in the opencv documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d0/d0a/classcv_1_1Tracker.html#a549159bd0553e6a8de356f3866df1f18). This is also an option when using dlib's [correlation_tracker](http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.correlation_tracker).

Currently, I can only initialize the tracker with a bounding box, but not update it with one in Python. if my tracker has drifted off the initial face it was tracking, I can't "bring it back" even if I know where the face is now (using my face detector). Is there a way to do this in python (e.g. should I kill the current tracker and init another with detected bounding box)?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Is it fast enough to kill the current tracker and init another one?

Comment: I did not find a solution yet (no answer from the dlib forum either). Fast enough depends on what you need to do.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: This is not possible in C++ neither, the "boundingBox" param of the C++ function is the output box of the function, not an input.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the very same thing and I found myself the solution to the problem by re-creating tracker each time successful detection occur. Please check following code. If something is not clear, feel free to ask for details:

```
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

face_front_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")    
tracker = cv.TrackerKCF_create()
bbox = ()

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()

    #press S to capture the face
    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord("s"):
        frame_gray = cv.cvtColor(frame,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        face = face_front_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=3)
        for (x, y, w, h) in face: 
            colour = (0,0,255)
            stroke = 20
            cv.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h), colour, stroke)
            bbox = (x,y,w,h)
            tracker = cv.TrackerKCF_create() #overwrite old tracker

    #trace face and draw box around it
    if bbox:
        tracker.init(frame, bbox)
        ret, bbox = tracker.update(frame)
        if ret:
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255, 0, 0), 2, 1)

    #show result
    cv.imshow("frame",frame)

    #press ESC to exit
    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF ==27:
        break    
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```